# How to visualize neo4j embedded database within a panel?

Tags: java, neo4j, visualize

I have developed a piece of software that creates an embedded graph database. I was wondering whether I can use a special feature to visualize it within my program without opening other tools. I am developing my software in JAVA using eclipse and windows builder. I have heard about some libraries like D3 or ZEST but I don't know how to use them. I really want something very easy to attach to a JPanel that shows the database stored in my neo4j folder(Something very simple).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at https://github.com/neo4j/neoclipse for some code using ZEST to start with.

Comment: This was a good tip but I still need help because despite having downloaded the source code I did't find the piece of code I was looking for. Anyway Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to visualize a Neo4j database, or any other kind of graph I cannot recommend [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) highly enough. It extends a well-documented Java api, which would make integration into your embedded application nearly trivial. Additionally there is a plugin that directly supports Neo4j integration so you don't even have to tackle that beast alone.

Even better Gephi comes with a GUI if you want to use it so that you can figure out exactly how you want to render your graph before integrating it (which saves on development time)